# In ggplot, how do you log scale the axis without messing up a linear regression

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I've got some data that I'm plotting and fitting a linear model. To display the data properly I need to log scale the x-axis. However, this messes up my linear model. Is there a way to log scale the axis without affecting the regression line.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
data <- structure(list(standard_conc_ngul = c(50, 50, 50, 5, 5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005), ct = c(18.3305377960205, 
18.133768081665, 17.8813705444336, 21.5002365112305, 21.4915542602539, 
22.7616996765137, 23.6836719512939, 25.3699340820312, 25.3488445281982, 
28.984302520752, 26.7397594451904, 27.8844776153564)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> print(data)
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   standard_conc_ngul    ct
                <dbl> <dbl>
 1             50      18.3
 2             50      18.1
 3             50      17.9
 4              5      21.5
 5              5      21.5
 6              0.5    22.8
 7              0.5    23.7
 8              0.05   25.4
 9              0.05   25.3
10              0.005  29.0
11              0.005  26.7
12              0.005  27.9
```

I can fit a model, like this, and get an r2 = 0.973.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = ct)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ log(x)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ log(x),
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3, 
               rr.digits = 3)
```

[image]

I want to display the lower values on the x-axis better, but when I try to log scale the x-axis it changes the model.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = ct)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ log(x)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ log(x),
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3, 
               rr.digits = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log2")
```

[image]

Is there a way to sort both the regression and the scaling?

Answer (score 1):

When using a log scale your data gets transformed before the `stat` is applied, i.e. your are running your model on the already transformed data. If it's not that important for you to have a `log2` scale then one option might be to use `y ~ x` with `trans="log"`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(data, aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = ct)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    formula = y ~ x,
    aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
    parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3,
    rr.digits = 3
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")
```

[image]